# Can I use my Ninject .NET project within Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, orchardcms, autofac

I am creating a website using Orchard CMS and I have an external .NET project written with Ninject for dependency injection which I would like to use together with a module within Orchard CMS. I know that Orchard uses Autofac for dependency injection and this is causing me problems since I never worked with DI before.

I have created an Autofac module, `UserModule`, which registers the a source, `UserRegistrationSource`, like this:

**UserModule.cs**

```
public class UserModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterSource(new UserRegistrationSource());
    }
}
```

**UserRegistrationSource.cs**

```
public class UserRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        var serviceWithType = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (serviceWithType == null)
            yield break;

        var serviceType = serviceWithType.ServiceType;
        if (!serviceType.IsInterface || !typeof(IUserServices).IsAssignableFrom(serviceType) || serviceType != typeof(IUserServices))
            yield break;

        var registrationBuilder = // something...

        yield return registrationBuilder.CreateRegistration();
    }
}
```

**UserServices.cs**

```
public interface IUserServices : IDependency
{
    void Add(string email, string password);
}

public class UserServices : IUserServices
{
    private readonly EFMembershipManager _manager;

    public UserServices(EFMembershipManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public void Add(string email, string password)
    {
        _manager.createUser(email, password);
    }
}
```

**EFMembershipManager.cs** constructor

```
public EFMembershipManager(ServerRepository db,
                           ServerRepositoryMembershipProvider membershipProvider,
                           string testUsername,
                           string serverUsername)
{
...
}
```

`EFMembershipManager` is a class from the external project which uses Ninject for DI's and uses `ServerRepository` and `ServerRepositoryMembershipProvider` whom also are injected using Ninject.

And now I'm stuck...

Should `UserRegistrationSource` take the Ninject container (kernel) as a constructor argument and try to find the `IUserServices` service and then mediate the resolves to the Ninject kernel and return an empty Enumerable so that Autofac doesn't try to resolve anything related to `IUserServices` or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Can you explain why it would need a rewrite? Seems to me like only what little code is dealing with injection would need to be modified. You mention problems. What are they specifically?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy The rewrite comes from the fact that the external project has a lot of dependency injections and references to other projects which also uses Ninject for dependency injection. So there will be a lot of modifications in order to get everything to work. The problem I'm facing is simply how I can reference the external project in my Orchard module without having to convert all Ninject injections to Autofac injections. If that's even possible.

Comment: I don't think there is another way or if you'll be able to make this work. Might be better to keep that external project external.

Comment: Do you have control over the Ninject container instance? If so, it should be easy to plug a registration source into the Autofac container that will mediate resolves to the Ninject container.

Comment: @PeterLillevold Yes I have control over the Ninject container instance. Where do I perform the registration into Autofac's container in Orchard? I am a complete newby when it comes to Autofac and DI's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autofac supports [registration sources](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/resolve-anything/) (and more on registration sources [here](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/)). A registration source is a service that the container will consult when trying to resolve a type. The source can respond, either with a means to build the type, or an empty list which indicates that the source is not able to provide the requested type.

In your case, a registration source could be implemented that will try to resolve the requested type from your Ninject container.

I'm not too familiar with Orchard but I'm guessing that it uses configuration files to configure Autofac. My suggestion is that you create [a simple Autofac module](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules) that registers your registration source implementation, and that you configure Orchard to [load the module from config](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/XmlConfiguration).

Comment: Okay, good answer. Some follow ups.. Should the registration source identify the service which is connected to the external project, `IUserServices`, and instruct the Ninject container (kernel) to resolve it and return an empty enumerable which tells Autofac not to resolve the requested types or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: My idea is that, since it will be Autofac that does the initial request for services, the source will be "asked" if it supports `IUserServices` (and every other service for that matter). It should then try to resolve that service from Ninject. If Ninject contains the service you can return the instance from the source. If not, the source returns empty.