# A self contained service DLL with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, orchardcms

I am looking for some best practice advice with regards to building a self contained service, that is a DLL with all of the domain logic and data layer.  I would like to use an off the self CMS, such as orchard, then talk to the service to carry out CRUD operations.  The service should have it's own IOC, and ORM, in this case I am using Ninject and Entity Framework. In this design I will have a separate database than the CMS, and can port it to other CMS systems when required.

The CMS should start the service and pass it a connection string or file name.  If I use orchard it has different ORM, and IOC frameworks, so this leads me to wanting to keep Ninject and Entity Framework inside the service.

I have setup an experiment where the DbConext and domain are in the service DLL, and I call it from a console app.  This only works if I have entity framework referenced in the console application, even though I don't use it in that dll.  Here is the error message when EF is not referenced by the console app.

No Entity Framework provider found for 'System.Data.SqlClient' ADO.NET provider.

Why is this and how best to solve my design problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your library (DLL) depends on Entity Framework, it's perfectly normal that you need to reference both in your application (whether it's console, web or whatever else). You always need to reference all dependencies.

Wiring your custom library with Orchard would be fairy simple. The only thing you'd need to do on Orchard side would be to register the services coming from your library with Autofac, in order to have them available for dependency injection. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143341/can-i-use-my-ninject-net-project-within-orchard-cms) describes a similar scenario to yours.

Please bear in mind that using multiple database connections is a bit troublesome in Orchard <= 1.6, because of the usage of `TransactionScope` - you need to run all your custom database code in a suppressed scope, otherwise you'd have transaction errors and/or MSDTC-related problems. It will be a non-issue since Orchard 1.7 which is going to arrive in about a week. I'd strongly recommend waiting for the new version. You can also fetch the pre-release code from `1.x` branch.